# Frontend trying to connect from internet to backend on Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, containers

I have 1 frontend (React) and backend (Java) inside a container on Docker. I mapped only frontend's IP address. I giving my containers IP address to my React app. But frontend cannot connect to backend and I cannot see anything at backend logs. When I mapping my backend port to internet frontend can connect.

My error is from frontend is;

```
POST http://172.17.0.4:5001/authenticate net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And when when I try this command I can get token.

```
curl -d '{  "username":"Admin","password":"Admin"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Origin: http://172.17.0.4:4300' http://172.17.0.4:5001/authenticate
```

How can I connect frontend to backend in same container on Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have forget to bind the container port to your local port.
When you run the container dont forget to: `docker run -p 5001:5001` **Where** the `-p`command is binding the port. And in this case you can use the API call with localhost `http://127.0.0.1:5001/authenticate`

Comment: but they are in same container.

Comment: Then try to use the localhost directly.

Comment: It's cannot connect. I getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. 172.17.0.4 this ip is my container ip. My other java applications can connect each other with this ip. But react cannot do that.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I would bind all port to my host, and connect them there together

Comment: Is it safe? If I have to mapping my backend port ,it would be security problem.

Comment: Well, it's a good question. I am not a security expert.

Comment: Than bind the ports to the host only in development, because you said, `When I mapping my backend port to internet frontend can connect.`